# Deploying Angular 8 Project after brotli compression

Tags: angular, iis, gzip, brotli

I have a project in Angular 8.
I have referred to https://medium.com/@subodhkumarjc/angular-build-optimization-part-2-compression-b866dd0593c3 to implement bortli compression in my project since my main.js files were coming pretty big in size after normal build.
After runing `ng build --prod`. I get the following set of dist files.
[File explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoaCY.png)

Now, generally to deploy this in IIS I just used to do a simple copy paste from my current local dist folder to my web folder pointed by  IIS in the server. But When I am trying to do the same thing, My browser is still loading the main.js file instead of the compressed main.js.br file.

Can anyone help me with what I am missing here while deploying.

**Note: As of now, I have not done any changes with my IIS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add the below code in your web.conifg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                
                <rule name="br_rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*).(js$|svg|css)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="br" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.{R:2}.br" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="gzip_rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*).(js$|svg|css)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="gzip" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.{R:2}.gz" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
                <rule name="Remove Server header" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite content-encoding header gzip" preCondition="IsGZ" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_ENCODING" pattern=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite content-encoding header br" preCondition="IsBR" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_ENCODING" pattern=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="br" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="css content type" preCondition="IsCSS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE" pattern="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="text/css" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="js content type" preCondition="IsJS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE" pattern="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="application/javascript" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="svg content type" preCondition="IsSVG" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE" pattern="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="image/svg+xml" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="IsGZ">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.gz$" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="IsBR">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.br$" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="IsCSS">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="css" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="IsJS">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="js" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="IsSVG">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="svg" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
        <httpCompression sendCacheHeaders="false" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".br" mimeType="application/brotli" />
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: web.config is my application.host.config file for my IIS ?

Comment: @ShivamThakur you need to add this code in the web.conifg file which is under your site folder.

Comment: @ShivamThakur were you able to make it work on IIS finally ?  I have the exact same issue and can't find a way out.

Comment: @ShivamThakur I got it working finally after struggling for 2 weeks.  my nod32 antivirus was disabling the gzip or brotli compression.  pausing it was not enought, I had to go to nod32 -> advanced setup -> Web and Email -> toggle off 'Enable SSL/TLS protocol filtering'.